# Distribution of exp with Rayleigh arg

Tags: random-variables

I am wondering what the distribution of

$$ y = exp(i\phi)$$

where $\phi$ is Rayleigh distributed and $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

My thought process to solve was to use LOTUS but I am unsure how to handle the $i$ as the arg into the Rayleigh distribution.

Comment: What is $i$? (Integer? Imaginary unit?)

Comment: LOTUS ? Do you refer to a yoga position in order to get inspiration ?

Comment: @angryavian Yes. Updated question.

Comment: @JeanMarie LOTUS = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: Thanks. Not lost my day... My second thought was that LOTUS was a new software I wasn't aware of.

Comment: More seriously, there is a problem because your definition would imply that Rayleigh distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) has a $2 \pi$  period... Truncating it to $[0,2\pi]$ wouldn't fix the problem because by doing that,  you would loose all the tail of the distribution...

Comment: @JeanMarie No, the phase is [0, inf] just like a rayliegh.

Comment: I understand now...